# Services and Control points using libupnp SDK for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sdk, ubuntu-12.04, upnp

How to make a service or control point using libupnp SDK?!

I didn't understand the documentation attached with this SDK, I don't know from where to start ?!

Can you help me in that and refer me to some helping tutorials ?!

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a good question for SO (see [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). As an aside, if you're targeting linux I really suggest not using libupnp -- there are much better options. I'm biased but will still suggest [GUPnP](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GUPnP): it has a clean API, is actively maintained and has lots of example code (see documentation and e.g. [BinaryLight example](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gupnp/tree/examples)). It's also widely available in distros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know, this is a very old question but still had no answer. I came here from google because I also was looking for an entry to use the libupnp SDK aka [Portable SDK for UPnP* Devices](https://github.com/mrjimenez/pupnp), but without success. So I will share how I  got it with some effort to find things.

I'm using Debian Stretch. So first I installed:

```
~$ sudo apt install libupnp6 libupnp6-dev libupnp6-doc
```

Then have a look at the documentation (of course ;) in `/usr/share/doc/libupnp6-doc/html/modules.html`. One of the problems was that I wasn't able to find this document online. With the *UPnP API* I started with this simple program, that searches for upnp devices on the local network. Just set `INTERFACE[]` and `SEARCH_DURATION_SECONDS` for what you need.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <upnp/upnp.h>

constexpr char INTERFACE[] = "eth0";
constexpr int SEARCH_DURATION_SECONDS = 5;


int callback_event_handler(Upnp_EventType event_type, void* event, void* cookie)
{
    std::string str;

    switch (event_type) {
        case UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_RESULT:
            str = "UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_RESULT";
            break;
        case UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_TIMEOUT:
            str = "UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_TIMEOUT";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Called callback_event_handler with ignored event" << std::endl;
            return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Executing callback_event_handler with event type " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << (char*)cookie << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr char cookie[] = "Free custom data, usable in the callback function.";
    UpnpClient_Handle client_handle = -1;

    UpnpInit2(INTERFACE, 0);
    UpnpRegisterClient(callback_event_handler, &cookie, &client_handle);
    UpnpSearchAsync(client_handle, SEARCH_DURATION_SECONDS, "upnp:rootdevice", cookie);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(SEARCH_DURATION_SECONDS + 1));
    UpnpFinish();
}
```

The search target (ST) **upnp:rootdevice** at `UpnpSearchAsync(..)` determins what to search. For other search targets look at [UPnP Device Architecture 1.0](http://www.upnp.org/specs/arch/upnp-arch-devicearchitecture-v1.0.pdf), chapter *1.2.2 Discovery: Search: Request with M-SEARCH*.

I compiled the program with:

```
~$ g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -lpthread -lupnp upnpsearch.cpp -o upnpsearch
```

If you execute it and you have UPnP devices on your local network you should get an output something like this:

```
Executing callback_event_handler with event type UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_RESULT
Free custom data, usable in the callback function.
Called callback_event_handler with ignored event
Called callback_event_handler with ignored event
Executing callback_event_handler with event type UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_RESULT
Free custom data, usable in the callback function.
Executing callback_event_handler with event type UPNP_DISCOVERY_SEARCH_TIMEOUT
Free custom data, usable in the callback function.
```

Here you see that two UPnP devices are online.